# How can we use '~|~' delimiter to split the records using scripting command?

Tags: shell, awk, delimiter

Please suggest how can I split the columns separated with **~|~** delimiter.(file: abc.dat)

```
a~|~1~|~x
b~|~1~|~y
c~|~2~|~z
```

I am trying below awk command but getting output 0 count.

```
awk -F'~|~' '$2 == 1' ${file} | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. We need not to use `wc` command along with `awk`, it could be done within `awk` itself.

```
awk -F'~\\|~' '$2 == 1{count++} END{print count}' "$file"
```

***Explanation:*** Setting field separator as `~|~`(escaped `|` here). Then checking if 2nd field is `1`, increment variable count with 1 then. In `END` block of this program print its value.

For saving values into shell variable use like:

```
var=$(awk -F'~\\|~' '$2 == 1{count++} END{print count}' "$file")
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, working as expected. can you please suggest how can we store the count into variable using your solution.

Comment: @R_Kalavadiya, use like: `var=$(awk -F'~\\|~' '$2 == 1{count++} END{print count}' "$file")` should be good IMHO.

Comment: Why is it necessary to `\\` the FS for awk?

Comment: @user1934428, to make it to treat it like literal character, see this once: `awk -F'~|~' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print i"...."$i}}' file1
1....a
2....|
3....1
4....|
5....x
1....b
2....|
3....1
4....|
5....y
1....c
2....|
3....2
4....|
5....z` its considering it like OR not like literal character.

Comment: I see - because the FS is treated as regexp! Forgot about this.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: sir, is there any difference in using double quotes and single quotes around the field separator(`-F`), like: `awk -F"~\\|~"` and `awk -F'~\\|~'` gives two different answers...

Comment: @User123, yes there is difference, when we wrap field separator with `"` then we need to use like `\\\\|` we need to escape \ too along with `|` because to make it understand its literal character \ and `|` we are talking about, that's why experts advice to use `\\|` in single quotes not in double quotes, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `~[|]~` as `FS` value, as the pipe char used inside a bracket expression always matches itself, a pipe char:

```sh
counter=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS="~[|]~"} $2==1{cnt++} END{print cnt}' file)
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/kQKmLJ):

```sh
s='a~|~1~|~x
b~|~1~|~y
c~|~2~|~z'
counter=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS="~[|]~"} $2==1{cnt++} END{print cnt}' <<< "$s")
echo $counter
# => 2
```